# google-maps-api-3 setCenter isn't working properly

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am just starting a new experience with google map API.
I am trying to get how it works and I usually understand or find my answers on forums.

I am having an issue with the `setCenter` property, and I can't find my mistake...
On click on a marker it should setCenter to the marker and zoom in. The `setCenter` isn't always working, sometimes, it `setCenter` few km away...

Here is my code:

```
var user;
var pos;

// Try HTML5 geolocation
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        // Show user marker
        user = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            title: 'My location',
            icon: iconUser,
            map: map,
            zIndex: google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1
        });

        map.setCenter(pos);

        // Get address
        geocoder.geocode({
            "latLng": pos
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    infowindow.setContent('<b>Here you are :</b><br />' + results[0].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, user);

                    // Show infowindow user marker click
                    google.maps.event.addListener(user, 'click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(null, null);
                        infowindow.setContent('<b>Here you are :</b><br />' + results[0].formatted_address);
                        infowindow.open(map, user);
                        map.setZoom(15);
                        map.setCenter("latLng");
                    });

                    // Hide infowindow map click
                    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
                        if (infowindow) {
                            infowindow.open(null, null);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Cannot determine address at this location.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });

    }, function () {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
}
```

If you could have a look, it would be great.

Comment: Which markers exhibit the problem?  Is it always the same ones?  If so, can you identify them?  You only posted the code for the geolocation functionality, is that where the problem is?

Comment: It seems that behaviour is random. Sometimes marker icons are not rendered correctly. After changing `map.setZoom(15); map.setCenter(this.position);` to `map.setCenter(this.position); map.setZoom(15);` I cannot repeat the problem (function `showQrcodes()`. And I don't know why is it so.

Comment: @geocodezip : the problem is happening with all of them... here is the geolocation, and i use the same code for others :)

Comment: @AntoJurković : it's freaking me out ! hahaha tks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `setCenter()` fails infowindow is not opened. It is so due to async nature of `geocoder.geocode()` call which is used in `showQrcodes` function. Function `setZoom()` and `setCenter()` and opening of infowindow have to be called in success function of `geocode()`.

I'd change `for` loop in `showQrcodes()` function to:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= locationArray.length - 1; i++) {
    coords = new google.maps.LatLng(locationArray[i][1], locationArray[i][2]);

    (function(i) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords,
        title: locationArray[i][0],
        map: map,
        icon: iconQr
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        console.log('showQrcodes marker onclick event listener');
        console.log(marker);

        infowindow.open(null, null);
        title = this.title;

        geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: this.position
        }, function (responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                infowindow.setContent('<b>' + title + ' : </b><br />' + responses[0].formatted_address);
                map.setZoom(15);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
                infowindow.setContent('Cannot determine address at this location.');
            }
        });

    });

    })(i);

}
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, thank you very very much for your help !

Comment: I can't vote because of my lack of reputation, but I give you a +10 000 :)